# Google Places API : OVER_QUERY_LIMIT issue is intermittent

Tags: python, google-api, google-places-api

I know this question has been asked before but mine is slightly different from other threads.

I've written a python script to read random addresses and to return their place ID. This is what my excel file looks like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces
import pandas as pd
import time
import xlrd
YOUR_API_KEY = <my_key>

google_places = GooglePlaces(YOUR_API_KEY)
loc = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.xlsx"

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(1,sheet.nrows):
    read_address = sheet.cell_value(i,0)
    query_result = google_places.text_search(
        query=''+read_address)
    for place in query_result.places:
        print(place.name)
        print(place.place_id)
```

Console Output:

```
C:\Users\csjeemah\PycharmProjects\googleplaces\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/csjeemah/PycharmProjects/googleplaces/googleplaceID.py
777 Brockton Ave
ChIJmf-3TW6b5IkR1rx0eohvqPQ
30 Memorial Dr
ChIJXa_KpmGD5IkRYtpt2IsXmqg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/csjeemah/PycharmProjects/googleplaces/googleplaceID.py", line 27, in <module>
    query_result = google_places.text_search(
  File "C:\Users\csjeemah\PycharmProjects\googleplaces\venv\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py", line 353, in text_search
    _validate_response(url, places_response)
  File "C:\Users\csjeemah\PycharmProjects\googleplaces\venv\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py", line 175, in _validate_response
    raise GooglePlacesError(error_detail)
googleplaces.GooglePlacesError: Request to URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=250+Hartford+Avenue%2C+Bellingham+MA+2019&radius=3200&language=en&key=mykey&sensor=false failed with response code: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

In the console screenshot above, it's returning the results for the first 2 addresses and then the error occurs.Now I understand the the reason I'm getting this error is due to a limit on the amount of requests I can make but as you can see from the image above:

1. there are only 9 addresses.

[image]

2. If I shorten a few of the addresses like those highlighted below:

[image]

It now retrieves more of the addresses before it fails:

```
C:\Users\csjeemah\PycharmProjects\googleplaces\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/csjeemah/PycharmProjects/googleplaces/googleplaceID.py
777 Brockton Ave
ChIJmf-3TW6b5IkR1rx0eohvqPQ
30 Memorial Dr
ChIJt_pwFGsUc2sR-ve6pnT9DlA
30 Memorial Dr
ChIJJatf08pZIWsRr2u-ppt2CyI
250 Hartford Ave
ChIJk567q-Jx5IkRGxbCzkmYU7A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/csjeemah/PycharmProjects/googleplaces/googleplaceID.py", line 27, in <module>
    query_result = google_places.text_search(
  File "C:\Users\csjeemah\PycharmProjects\googleplaces\venv\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py", line 353, in text_search
    _validate_response(url, places_response)
  File "C:\Users\csjeemah\PycharmProjects\googleplaces\venv\lib\site-packages\googleplaces\__init__.py", line 175, in _validate_response
    raise GooglePlacesError(error_detail)
googleplaces.GooglePlacesError: Request to URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=700+Oak+Street&radius=3200&language=en&key=mykey&sensor=false failed with response code: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

I've also tried to add a sleep for a few seconds after each query but it fails, could anyone tell me what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The error json in the image clearly states that you have exceeded your daily request quota for places API.

If you wish to continue you need to associate your GCP project to the billing account

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the documentation [Usage Limits for Google Maps Platform Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits)

You can exceed the Google Maps Platform web services usage limits by:

- Sending too many requests per day.
- Sending requests too fast, i.e. too many requests per second.
- Sending requests too fast for too long or otherwise abusing the web service.
- Exceeding other usage limits, e.g. points per request in the Elevation API.

Upon receiving a response with status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application should determine which usage limit has been exceeded. This can be done by pausing for 2 seconds and resending the same request. If status code is still OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, your application is sending too many requests per day. Otherwise, your application is sending too many requests per second.

```
url = "MAPS_API_WEBSERVICE_URL"
attempts = 0
success = False

while success != True and attempts < 3:
  raw_result = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  attempts += 1
  # The GetStatus function parses the answer and returns the status code
  # This function is out of the scope of this example (you can use a SDK).
  status = GetStatus(raw_result)
  if status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":
    time.sleep(2)
    # retry
    continue
  success = True

if attempts == 3:
  # send an alert as this means that the daily limit has been reached
  print "Daily limit has been reached"
```